# How a kingdom or an empire formed?

Tags: monarchy

I wonder at the beginning when people form a country, how do they choose their first ever king or queen? How is a monarchy formed?

Comment: The question is poorly formed,and you misunderstand a lot.  The people rarely choose. Usually a group of people give the strongest warrior benefits for keeping them safe.  He collects power and starts ruling.  Otherwise, a King seizes power from an existing government. Kings tend to be made through violence. Royal blood is meaningless. The Royal Descent / Divine Right is a lie told after a King seizes power to legitimize his rule and to prevent others from doing what he just did. Namely killing him and seizing the throne. So you shouldn't kill the King, because he was meant to be King not you.

Comment: So after they have choose a warrior,then if the people wants to become a monarchy then he'll become the first king?

Comment: Rarely, usually he just accumulates power and noone is brave enough to stop him.  Or he just kills anyone who tries. Although, this process can be gradual. There could be 100 first warriors before one of them decides he should just kill the elected "chief" and be the new "chief." But this new "chief" is more powerful, since he is also the first warrior. Essentially a king.

Comment: Also, a King does not necessarily mean a "country" exists. The concept of a country is a bit different than a kingdom. A King typically had hundreds of distinct titles, and ruled many different people. So what we would term the "French" were actually many different people groups who only recently became "French."

Comment: And if we are in 2017 and a kingdom will rise from a no king or queen,then from where they choose to be a king or queen and who?

Comment: That is unlikely. A Kingdom does not typically come out of nowhere. Typically, there is someone leading the push that wants to be king. Who makes the kingdom happen. The only other way is that a new country is created, from a people who share a common link, who choose to have a monarchy.  This does not happen a lot. At this point the leader is typically chosen from the nobles or leaders who made this new kingdom. (Again, usually someone would just seize control).  You could also make the kingdom elective.  But this is now. When the concept of monarchy already exists, not the past

Comment: The entire point of a Monarchy is that "the people" have no choice in the matter.

Comment: Start here: [_complex society_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_society)

Comment: Aaaa,I understand now.

Comment: Related, about what is the interest of the other people in allowing a King to be King: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ig_qpNfXHIU.. but in order to understand that you might want to first see this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rStL7niR7gs

Comment: Too broad.  There is no fully general pattern.

Comment: @user2259716 Thanks for the marxist-leninist-revolutionary rewriting of history (i.e. kings grabbed power by force) when this is in fact unsourced and completely false.

Comment: @Bregalad What do you think a King or a Noble is? Violence created those positions (either directly or as a result of protecting against it) and a combination of violence and apathy secured them. (Apathy being people being unwilling to change it. People do so many things because "that is how it has always been.") I would be really interested if you could find literally any line of Kings who did not murder each other to take the crown. Even within their own family. History is one of violence. To pretend otherwise is foolish.

Comment: Comments should not be used for discussion. Please move to chat

Answer (score 2):

A monarchy is often formed during a time of war, when a successful and popular general is crowned king.

In the Bible, for instance, King Saul was anointed by the prophet Samuel as King of Israel, but his "dynasty" lasted only one generation because Saul was not successful in war.

But his successor, David, started as a private soldier in Saul's army, quickly rose to captain, eventually formed his own army, defeated the Philistines and other enemies, and became king. His dynasty lasted in some way shape or form for several hundred years.

Rome started out as a Republic, but was eventually embroiled in a number of foreign wars and some civil wars. Its most successful general, Julius Caesar, "crossed the Rubicon" with his army and became king of Rome.

Comment: Not a word on electoral monarchies?

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: I said "A monarchy is often formed during a time of war..." I didn't cover every case. And even in the instance of "electoral" monarchies, war or threat of war has something to do with it (e.g. with regard to the Holy Roman Empire), and the election of the most promising "warlord." I regard such electoral monarchies as "special cases" of monarchies started by popular acclamation.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - The "electorate" of electoral monarchies tends to be appallingly limited. Still, its always nice when the upper classes can find a way to decide on our next ruler without gathering armies and trampling all our crops.

Answer (score 1):

**Monarchy happens when people believe in the right of kings (and queens).**

Consider how *most* monarchies developed.

- There was an area with several tribes. Many had [chieftains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dux#Post-Roman_uses), and that might have been a hereditary office. At the very least, a child of the previous chieftain had better chances to get the job than a random peasant.
- One of those tribes became more powerful, and that tribal leader was elevated above the other chieftains. He or she got a different title and the others took an oath of [fealty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fealty).
- For a long time, the approval of the Pope helped to confirm legitimacy.

Then a lot of history happened. Some monarchies disappeared again, others prospered. [Ursurpers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usurper) stole the throne but did not question the monarchy, [revolutionaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glorious_Revolution) overthrew the monarchy, counterrevolutionaries restored it.

Of course that raises the question where chieftains came from. Same principle, in a smaller area ...

Comment: Not a word on electoral monarchies?